# Unable to get value via two parameter in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Here is the code I write to get value form API, Is it possible to send the two parameter like i send in the following example.

```
async getMainAssignmentsList(schoolId,lessonId) {
  var getLearningStrategiesUrl =
    this.apiBasedUrl + 'Assignment/' + schoolId +'/'+ lessonId + '/GetMainAssignment'
  await this.axios
    .get(getLearningStrategiesUrl)
    .then(response => {
      this.mainAssignmentList = response.data
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error)
    })
}
```

My requirement is that I need to select First 'form.schoolId' and after that 'form.lessonId' and on the basis of combined want to show data but, here is am unable to send parameter in the API.

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <b-form-select v-model="form.schoolId"  class="mt-2" placeholder="Please select an option" @input="getMainAssignmentsList(form.schoolId)">
        <option :value="null">Select school</option>
        <option  v-for="School in allSchoolsList" :value="School.id" :key="School.id">{{School.schoolName}}</option>
    </b-form-select>
 </div>
<div class="col-sm-12" >
       <b-form-select v-model="form.lessonId" class="mt-2"  @input="getMainAssignmentsList(form.lessonId)">
              <option :value="null">Please select Lesson</option>
              <option v-for="Lesson in allLessons" v-bind:value="Lesson.id" :key="Lesson.id">{{Lesson.name}}</option>
          </b-form-select>
   </div>
    <!--- Here want to show value in drop down --->
<div class="col-sm-12" >
        <b-form-select v-model="parentAssignmentId" class="mt-2" >
                 <option :value="null">Please select Main Assignment</option> 
                 <option v-for="MainAssignment in mainAssignmentList" v-bind:value="MainAssignment.id" :key="MainAssignment.id">{{AssignmentTypes.name}}</option>
         </b-form-select>
  </div>
```

Currently my URL is showing following value:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:51711/api/Assignment/undefined/undefined/GetMainAssignment
```

Comment: from reading the code you posted i don't think the value you are getting from your drop down is being passed back to your form object. double check the first and second example here: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-select/

Answer (score 1):

You can always try something like this and let bootstrap-vue take care of most of the heavy lifting.

```
<template>
  <b-container>
    <b-row>
      <b-col sm="12">
        <b-form-select
          v-model="selectedSchoolId"
          class="mt-2"
          placeholder="Please select an option"
          :options="allSchoolsList"
        ></b-form-select>
      </b-col>
      <b-col sm="12">
        <b-form-select v-model="selectedLessonId" class="mt-2" :options="allLessons"></b-form-select>
      </b-col>
      <b-col sm="12">
        <b-form-select
          v-model="parentAssignmentId"
          class="mt-2"
          placeholder="Please select Main Assignment"
          :options="mainAssignmentList"
        ></b-form-select>
      </b-col>
      <b-col>
        <b-btn @click="getMainAssignmentsList">Submit</b-btn>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </b-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selectedLessonId: null,
      selectedSchoolId: null,
      parentAssignmentId: null,
      allSchoolsList: [
        { value: null, text: "Please select an option" },
        { value: "schoola", text: "School A" },
        { value: "schoolb", text: "School B" },
        { value: "schoolc", text: "School C" },
        { value: "schoold", text: "School D" }
      ],
      allLessons: [
        { value: null, text: "Please select an option" },
        { value: "lessona", text: "Lesson A" },
        { value: "lessonb", text: "Lesson B" },
        { value: "lessonc", text: "Lesson C" },
        { value: "lessond", text: "Lesson D" }
      ],
      mainAssignmentList: [
        { value: null, text: "Please select an option" },
        { value: "assignmenta", text: "Assignment A" },
        { value: "assignmentb", text: "Assignment B" },
        { value: "assignmentc", text: "Assignment C" },
        { value: "assignmentd", text: "Assignment D" }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getMainAssignmentsList() {
      let apiArgs = {
        lesson: this.selectedLessonId,
        school: this.selectedSchoolId
      };
      console.log(apiArgs);
      //Call API using apiArgs
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I removed the options tags and changes some divs to b-col tags. If you want to manual make your own options tags you will need to use the correct tag like this example taken straight from the docs:

```
<b-form-select-option value="C">Option C</b-form-select-option>
```

[image: Edit Answer for Vipin Jha]